# Is $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \sum_{i=n}^1 i$

Tags: summation, arithmetic

When I enter these expressions into wolfram I get that they're not equal. Why is this? Essentially I'm trying to say $$ 1+2+\cdots+n = n+(n-1)+\cdots+1 $$

Comment: Try it as sum for I from 1 to n of (n+1-i). The computer algebra evaluation does it as increasing the i from its initial value up by 1 each time while it's less than the top, so would give a different thing for the right expression.

Comment: To add to what coffeemath said, wolframalpha is automatically assuming that $n\leq 1$.

Comment: What is the formal definition of $\sum$ symbol?

Comment: In a computer code like mathematica $\sum_{i=n}^1 i$ might be defined and give some answer, but in formal mathematics one never uses this notation!

Comment: What is the notation in formal math?

Comment: You'd use $\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)$ or $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)$ or something similar. (In general, $\sum_{n=a}^b$ automatically assumes that $a\le b$.)

Comment: If you have to choose between those two, choose $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ instead of $\sum_{i=n}^1 i$. As columbus said above: the largest number should be on top.